# Why is my ListView not clickable when it contains a RatingBar in a TableRow?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-tablelayout

When I have a RatingBar in a TableRow on my ListView, my `onListItemClick` isn't being fired when I touch a row. When I either do `bar.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or just remove the control, the rows are clickable again.

How do I make it so that when I add a RatingBar, `onListItemClick` still gets fired for the row? I've tried setting the `focusable="false"` but it still doesn't work.

IDEAS????

Here's my XML for the RatingBar in a TableRow:

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2x"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RatingBar 
      android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="3.5"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
      android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
      android:isIndicator="false"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
      style="@style/starRatingBar"  
/>  

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
```

And here's my code:

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        //... does stuff
    }
```

Comment: When you say `onListItemClick` is not being ran, are we talking about that while index in the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick Event have been intercepted by RatingBar, so The onListItemClick Will not be fired.

You can extend the RatingBar class, and override the onTouchEvent method, return false.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the RatingBar to this will fix the Issue
ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true);